# Cannot install react loading skeleton

Tags: reactjs

After having uninstalled my "react-loading-skeleton" for my react project, but when reinstall it always bring up an error telling me that
[image: error message]

Comment: Which react version do you have for your project?

Comment: "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.2.0"

Comment: I meant React.js version

Comment: "react": "16.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

On image you attached I see emotion/core from react-loading-skeleton requires react>=16.3.0 . Try to upgrade react version to 16.3.0 or downgrade version of react-loading-skeleton

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: Please let me know if it works. If you share your package.json file it also could help to understand what's wrong with dependencies

Comment: Sr too late !  You know, that really works. So thanks for the advice.